# Problem with Parallelization when using Packages

Tags: parallelization

I tried to find a solution to my problem in several answers posted in MSE but due to lack of my knowledge on parallelization territory, I couldn't figure out solution to my problem.

I have a big code with several Packages (with private contexts in each package) in addition to call some of MMA packages. The computations takes around 10 hours (which is too long time for my goal) and it gets worse  when run this code tens of times !!!

The general structure of the code is as follows:

[image]

I am trying now to use the parallelization technique to reduce the processing time. I thought first to use `ParallelDo` but it did not work. After reading through documentation and several answers in MSE I realized that `ParallelDo` is not the right way to parallelize the code. According to what I understand, I thought to parallelize the parts that are inside the red rectangles in the picture.

I first tried Parallelization on the first rectangle as follows:

```
Do[
 Parallelize[{"SQL data1+Processing", "SQL data2+processing", 
   "SQL data3+processing"}];
 Rest of the code ...,
 {Do Variable}]
```

I got tons of errors with all indicate that Kernels did not recognized the call of the Packages and their functions.

My question is how to use Parallelization  in this case?

Thank you

**Update:**

**Here is a minimal example of my problem:**

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
f::usage="Test function 1";
g::usage="Test function 2";
n::usage="Test Number";
str::usage="Test string"
Begin["`Private`"];
f[x_]:=Module[{},
n=IntegerPart[x^2]];
g[list_]:=Total[list];
str:=RandomSample[{"a","b","c","d","e","f"},3];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Now if I use `Do` as follows it works:

```
Get["Test.m"]
result1 = {};
result2 = {};
result3 = {};
Do[
 r11 = f[#] & /@ Range[i];
 r12 = g[r11];
 str1 = StringMatchQ[StringJoin@str, "*a*"];
 AppendTo[result1, {r12, str1}];

 r21 = f[#] & /@ Range[i + 1];
 r22 = g[r21];
 str2 = StringMatchQ[StringJoin@str, "*a*"];
 AppendTo[result2, {r22, str2}];

 r31 = f[#] & /@ Range[i + 3];
 r32 = g[r31];
 str3 = StringMatchQ[StringJoin@str, "*a*"];
 AppendTo[result3, {r32, str3}];
 ,
 {i, 1, 5}]
```

But this does not work:

```
Get["Test.m"]
result1 = {};
result2 = {};
result3 = {};
Do[
 Parallelize[{
   r11 = f[#] & /@ Range[i];
   r12 = g[r11];
   str1 = StringMatchQ[StringJoin@str, "*a*"];
   AppendTo[result1, {r12, str1}];,

   r21 = f[#] & /@ Range[i + 1];
   r22 = g[r21];
   str2 = StringMatchQ[StringJoin@str, "*a*"];
   AppendTo[result2, {r22, str2}];,

   r31 = f[#] & /@ Range[i + 3];
   r32 = g[r31];
   str3 = StringMatchQ[StringJoin@str, "*a*"];
   AppendTo[result3, {r32, str3}];
   }]
 ,
 {i, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: What portions of the code take most of the time?  Also, remember that `DistributeDefinitions` or `ParallelNeeds` sometimes must be used.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The computation inside the first two red rectangular take most of the time (each Do cycle takes around 4 sec and the total number of the Do cycles are around 9000). Does `DistributeDefinitions` means declare all symbols that has to be known to all kernels, I have hundreds of them including those in the privet contexts !!!

Comment: @bbgodfrey I just tried using `ParallelNeeds` but still symbols belong to loaded packages are not recognized by sub kernels

Comment: I do not have good answers to your questions.  Is it possible to provide code for the initial loop?  Despite your diagram, I do not have a good feel for the structure of the code.

Comment: Can you try to create a minimal example with *some* package?  Did you call `ParallelNeeds` before or after launching the kernels?  Call if *afterwards* only because otherwise any error messages that might be printed will be suppressed.  `ParallelNeeds` is absolutely necessary for the package to be usable on the subkernels.

Comment: @Szabolcs please see the update. Thank you

Comment: There are two problems I see: 1. you must use `ParallelNeeds` to make the package available on the subkernels. If the package is in a special location, and you set `$Path` so Mathematica can find it, you must also separately set path on the subkernels (use `ParallelEvaluate`).  2. Variables aren't shared between subkernels and the main kernels, only copied.  `result1` is different on the main kernel and subkernel.  When you have a lot of `AppendTo`, it's not easy to parallelize effectively.  `SetSharedVariable` can emulate variable sharing by evaluating/setting the variable on the main kernel.

Comment: This makes access that variable really slow.  This is only worth it computing the value that you are going to append is much slower than the variable access.

Comment: @Szabolcs it works but I need to use both Needs and` ParallelNeeds` in this example. I am since yesterday trying to implement this solution to my real code but still errors happen. One thing I want to mention here is that when I place the package in other location (other than any of the `$Path`) and use `Get`, and then `ParallelNeeds`, it works without any need to specify the current package location to the sub kernels !!